# How would I do a unit test for the day of the month and the day of the week

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing

I want to test both day of the week and day of the month for java calendar. I have been trying to figure out test classes for the past few hours.
I want to feed the day of the week values and test if the day of the week will come out as expected. any help will be appreciated.
I think I need to feed it a day, month, and year, but i dont know how to this.
I need to use calendar for this coding exercise.

my code so far

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dayOfWeek {


public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


    //Input Day
    System.out.println("Enter the Day (last two numbers) in number format:");
    int day= input.nextInt( );

    //Input Month
    System.out.println("Enter the Month (last two numbers) in number format:");
    int month= input.nextInt( );

    //Input Year
    System.out.println("Enter the Year (last two numbers) in number format:");
    int year= input.nextInt( );


    c.set(year, month, day);

    //Display the day
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    // Display Day of month
    int dayOfMonth = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //Print date in format
    System.out.println(String.format("%d/%d/%d",day,month,year));


    //if statement to print out day of week
    if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        System.out.println("Sunday");
    }
    else if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.MONDAY) {
        System.out.println("Monday");
    }
    else if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.TUESDAY) {
            System.out.println("Tuesday");
    }
    else if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.WEDNESDAY) {
                System.out.println("Wednesday");
    }
    else if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.THURSDAY) {
        System.out.println("Thursday");
    }
    else if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.FRIDAY) {
        System.out.println("Friday");
    }
    else if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY) {
        System.out.println("Saturday");






    //close Scanner in 
    input.close( );

   }

}

public static Object dayOfWeek(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Move the logic to a method and pass in a `PrintStream` instead of hard-coding `System.out` inline. (And use a map or array instead of the chained `if`s.)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

- Never use the terrible `Calendar` class.
- The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes.

## `LocalDate`

Parse your three integers as a date. Capture the exception thrown if the input is invalid, if no such date exists. Use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
try {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( y , m , d ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeException e ) {
    … handle invalid input …
}
```

## `DayOfWeek`

Pass your expected day-of-week using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum such as [`DayOfWeek.MONDAY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#MONDAY).

```
DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.MONDAY ;  // Passed into your test.
if( ld.getDayOfWeek().equals( dow ) ) { … }
```

## Convert

If you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back-and-forth. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

If you need a [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), a [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) more specifically, we need a time-of-day and a time zone.

You will likely want to use the first moment of the day. Never assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Now convert.

```
Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;  // Convert from modern class to legacy class. Do so only if absolutely required; otherwise, avoid the legacy date-time classes like the Plague.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I need to use the calendar class

Comment: @Mark Okay, I added a "Convert" section. But I strongly suggest you abandon the wretched mess that is `Date`/`Calendar`/`SimpleDateFormat` etc. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on these classes years ago, and so should you.